# Embed Youtube video in Flash CS4?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, youtube

Is there any way to play Youtube content in a Flash movie without using a third party plugin?

I'm using Flash CS4 and Actionscript 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the YouTube ActionScript Player API:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/flash_api_reference.html